# Explain plan MySQL on empty database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-performance

I have a copy of the schema of a database in MySQL 5.6 (+ Percona toolkit) because I have to evaluate the performance of the queries put on an app (and report them in order to take measures for optimizing queries/schema). This schema (for security reasons) is not filled with data and original tables might have between 100k-10 records.

I'm running Explain on the queries (using MySQL Workbench 6.3), but seems useless because It doesn't show all the analysis. Example: An Explain for a (known working) Select query joining three tables shows the message "Impossible where noticed after reading const tables".

So, the questions are:

- It's useless running Explain on an empty database?
- How can I get a reliable Explain for the queries I have to review?

Comment: 1) yes, practically useless. (the EXPLAIN will perform a syntax/semantics check, and throw an error for an invalid statement)  2) run EXPLAIN against a database that has representative data values and volumes. EXPLAIN is only one of the tools in the bag. Consider identifying slow queries by temporarily enabling slow_query_log.

Comment: Pretty short, but very useful. I'll enable slow log. =)

Comment: If you would like, show us the `SELECT` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE(s)`.  It is often possible to partially optimize queries without any data and without seeing the `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the query, but yes, I often recommend that you need to fill the tables with some sample data to get accurate EXPLAIN reports.

Even if you fill with 1 row so you avoid the "impossible where" note, that's not good enough because a table with very few rows is likely to be treated specially by the optimizer. That is, the optimizer knows that such a small table will fit on a single page of storage anyway, and the minimum unit the storage engine will retrieve is one page, so it may do a "table scan" instead of using an index, whereas it would be important to use an index for the same query if the table had a few thousand rows.

You don't necessarily need to fill the table with real, sensitive data. It's common to write a script to generate meaningless data that is *similar* to your real data, enough to fill the tables so you can test.

You don't necessarily need to fill 100k rows of data to get EXPLAIN to show you the same optimizer plan it would use for that much data. It's good enough if you can fill the tables with a few hundred or a few thousand rows of artificial data.

Comment: It's a great explanation. I suspected that data quantity influenced Explain, but I wouldn't imagine it could be so much. I'll try to generate representative data.

Comment: MySQL does a lot to try to be smart and efficient about reducing page reads. If it knows it will have to read 1-2 pages for a small table, it's wasteful to double the reads by reading 1-2 index pages as well.